# Procedure with @tpv not working from c#

Tags: c#, sql, procedure

I have a procedure in Sql that get @tpv as a parameter. when I exec the procedure from c# - It is not working, and when I exec the procedure from Sql - It's working perfect. Why?

Edit: when I exec the proc from c# - it is not get an error, seem like it is work fine, but the table didn't change at all and `misRow=0` instead of `misRow=1`.

Procedure:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[UpdateAdsList]
@tvp ListCrc32 readonly
as
 update tb
 set a_update=CONVERT(date,GETDATE(),101)
 from Ads tb
 join @tvp t on t.crc32 = a_crc32
```

Exec from Sql:

```
declare @ ListCrc32

insert into @ (crc32)
select 1652908150

exec UpdateAdsList @
```

Exec from C#:

```
int mis=1652908150;

//create the dataTable
dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("crc32", typeof(int));
var row = dt.NewRow();
row["crc32"] = mis;
dt.Rows.Add(row);

//exec the proc
con.Open();
var cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateAdsList",con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@tvp",SqlDbType.Structured);
cmd.Parameters["@tvp"].Value = dt;
cmd.Parameters["@tvp"].TypeName = "ListCrc32";
int misRow=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.close();
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? You get an error? If so what?

Comment: I don't know if it makes any difference, but just wondering. Your column is typeof(int), why do you convert mis to double ?

Comment: @Dumitrescu Bogdan, I tried it without convert, no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to add the parameter without the type:

```
int mis=1652908150;

//create the dataTable
dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("crc32", typeof(int));
var row = dt.NewRow();
row["crc32"] = mis; // I do not see the point of convert.
dt.Rows.Add(row);

//exec the proc
var cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateAdsList",con);
cmd.CommandType = Syste.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvp",dt);

con.Open();

int misRow=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.close();
```

Comment: It raises an error: "table type parameter '@ tvp' must be a valid type."

Comment: Fun .. there is no reason for that error as long as the type is well defined in the db.

Comment: The type is well defined in my db. I don't know why it raises the error.